# dnsmasq does not resolv dns subdomains that are forwarding to the domain

Tags: dns, router, dnsmasq

i have a strange problem with dnsmasq. It does not resolv dns subdomains that are directing to domains.

Example:

https://t.newsletter.otto.de/r/?id=h494cd19e%2C323e1c29%2C25c7c155&p1=1&p2=8CE3224E34213CB27C53429FC9F9E6D0&s=K037dtKC2c5tDwKORBNJIUdsKPz94HMDIV68TPWOqoA

This is the domain in a e-mail newsletter. And if everything works well and you open the dns you get redirected to a product on the page [www.otto.de](http://www.otto.de)

But my configuration of dnsmasq does get a timeout while opening the long dns.

It does not help to change the dns server from provider dns server to google dns server (8.8.8.8).

And also if i change on the client in resolv.conf the dns server to google dns server it does not help. In iptables i have just the masquerading rule and all chains on accept. If i connect on my notebook to the hotspot of my mobile phone everything runs OK. Below two dns lookups. The first google dns lookup while in the network where this dns redirection did not work. And the second dns lookup while connected to the hotspot of my mobile phone where the redirection works.

```
root@localhost:/etc# dig https://t.newsletter.otto.de

<<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u3-Debian <<>> https://t.newsletter.otto.de
global options: +cmd
Got answer:
->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 25663
flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
QUESTION SECTION:
https://t.newsletter.otto.de.   IN  A

AUTHORITY SECTION:
newsletter.otto.de. 899 IN  SOA ns-261.awsdns-32.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200       900 1209600 86400

Query time: 33 msec
SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
WHEN: Wed Mar 24 17:16:04 UTC 2021
MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138

root@localhost:/etc# dig https://t.newsletter.otto.de

<<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u3-Debian <<>> https://t.newsletter.otto.de
global options: +cmd
Got answer:
->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 57612
flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
QUESTION SECTION:
https://t.newsletter.otto.de.   IN  A

AUTHORITY SECTION:
newsletter.otto.de. 841 IN  SOA ns-261.awsdns-32.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200     900 1209600 86400

Query time: 21 msec
SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
WHEN: Wed Mar 24 17:17:02 UTC 2021
MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138
```

My dnsmasq config:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=10.0.0.1
listen-address=192.168.1.1
dhcp-range=set:green,192.168.1.100,192.168.1.254,24h
dhcp-range=tag:green,192.168.1.100,192.168.1.254,24h
dhcp-range=set:wlan,10.0.0.100,10.0.0.254,24h
dhcp-range=tag:wlan,10.0.0.100,10.0.0.254,24h
dhcp-option=tag:wlan,3,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=tag:green,3,192.168.1.1
```

Comment: There are lots of variables here. You've shown us a web URL but you're talking about DNS. What does `dig t.newsletter.otto.de` show the name resolves to? Is it the right place? If it is then DNS isn't the problem

Comment: but what could be the problem? If i click the link it does open in a browser and than timeout occurs... That points to me like it would be a dns problem. Because the browser cannot open the url...

Comment: No, not necessarily. Please update your question to answer what I've asked

Comment: You're also using `dig` wrongly. It takes a domain name, not a URL